# ASP.Net MVC 4 - Dictionary Parameter in Controller Action

Tags: dictionary, parameters, asp.net-mvc-4, controller, action

I've found a couple of questions like the one below, but all I've found where in previous versions of MVC, is there something new in MVC 4 for this?

[Optional Dictionary Parameter in MVC 3 Controller Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392966/optional-dictionary-parameter-in-mvc-3-controller-action)

**UPDATE: with some code to help future visitors**

```
public class QueryStringDictionaryBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var querystrings = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

        return querystrings.Cast<string>()
          .Select(s => new { Key = s, Value = querystrings[s] })
          .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead relying on a specific format of your post data and hoping the MVC binder would be able to understand it, I would go with implementing a custom model binder, where you can parse your post values and build the dictionary object.

Here's a sample code of how to implement it, it's very easy and highly flexible.

See my answer.

[Bind MvcContrib grid contents to view model on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494156/bind-mvccontrib-grid-contents-to-view-model-on-postback/13495443#13495443)

Comment: I just did that, and will add my code tomorrow for other people as it's very difficult to find.